# RFID tags writing

Tags: rfid

I'm planning to create a stock manager based on RFID. At this moment I'm Newby using this technology. I was looking around for info about how to write custom data on a tag (for instance, name of the product, production date and so) but can't find anything.

I would like to know how to store the info (maybe an array I guess) and how to read/write it.

Hope you people can suggest me a good book or tutorial.

Many thanks, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In modern RFID system design, we seldom write too much information into Tag. That is because most RFID system you can buy using EEPROM storage. Therefore, writing to tag may cost as least 5 times resource than reading tags. You need more time and shorter distance to write and verify single tag. As my experience, writing-to-tag may be needed only in some special situation, such as distributed JIT manufacturing or anti-counterfeit applications. I recommend you take the advantage of reading unique-ID and let the detail information being handled by traditional database system.

The typical processing steps would be:

1. Binding phase: Read unique ID of RFID tags (such UID in HF or EPC of UHF system) and save the relationship with UID and record index in Database. For example, in case-tagging, save both UID and product SKU in the same record.
2. Update phase: update business information in database based on the reading result. For example, update product import/export time for those records that own such UID reading at dock door.
3. Query phase: retrieve information based on reading result.

Comment: Tanks for your reply. I'm considering writing tag just once. After that, scanner will only read info. I'm planning to do this because i'm implementing a "search product" function, to ease finding an element in a warehouse.

Comment: With respect to warehouse, the most probably tags you may use are ISO18000-6C tags (also known as C1G2 or EPC tag). You would find there are rarely memory space you can use (96 ~ 512bits). Anyway, you can search the EPCglobal "Tag Data Standard" as your reference. Besides, many readers support "LLRP", which is the reader protocol that specify how to interactive with reader to read/write tags. Sometimes, you may need proprietary reader protocol provided by the manufacture of reader (such as 3M, Alien, etc). Those documents will define how to send packet/payload via TCP/IP or serial comm.